# Is there a way for me to put advertisements on my Extension? (Chrome Extension, Microsoft Addons)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge, ads

I have made a popular extension but I am trying to put advertisements on there.
Below is my code.
Dont worry about the document. Look at the code below.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1TQTJi7j0seWcfyC8w5DyNn3Ov9dMvcPFGzt7OcADKDw/edit?usp=sharing

The code works when I put it in a Html Tester. It shows the advertisement. But when I test it as an extension the advertisement does not appear but the game does. Is there a reason?

Is there a way I can fix it?
Thanks

```html
<html>
    <head>

    <body>
      
<script type="text/javascript">
    atOptions = {
        'key' : '158047a6e4d1f2e9957e2ce46ec501a4',
        'format' : 'iframe',
        'height' : 90,
        'width' : 728,
        'params' : {}
    };
    document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http' + (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 's' : '') + '://extractplayed.com/158047a6e4d1f2e9957e2ce46ec501a4/invoke.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
</script>
  



<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   
               <form action="https://stackoverflow.com/" method="get" class="inline" target="myiframe">
         <button type="submit">testing</button>
        </form>
        <iframe name="myiframe" height="545" width="750"></iframe>
        
               
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code can not be put on the question. Most of the code disappears. it is a HTML. It doesn't work.

Comment: It is a very short code but the <head> <body> and <script> thing disappears when I put it in.

Comment: Sorry, for the code snippet I used ''' instead of ```. That was why it is not working.

Comment: I think it's because you use remote scripts which leads to it doesn't work in extension. From [this doc](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#remotely-hosted-code), we can know that *In Manifest V3, all of your extension's logic must be bundled with the extension. You can no longer load and execute a remotely hosted file.* In your code, there's JavaScript file pulled from a remote server, it can't be executed in extension. I suggest you migrate the remote js code to local extension bundle or refer to the suggestions in the doc.

Comment: Well, the extension works fine but it is just the advertisement that is not showing.

Comment: @YuZhou So is it possible that I could execute a remotely hosted file?

Comment: I think it's impossible. From the doc, it says *You can no longer load and execute a remotely hosted file.*

Comment: @YuZhou Thank you, but what about Microsoft addons?

Comment: They're the same. They are both based on chromium. You can also refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/developer-guide/migrate-your-extension-from-manifest-v2-to-v3#remotely-hosted-code).

Comment: @YuZhou Is a remotely hosted file the same as an embed? Like, embed a website on an extension? If it is, in the extension, I have remotely hosted another website on the extension. If you try the code above in an Html tester you will see what I mean.              Thank you!

Comment: I think the script `https://extractplayed.com/158047a6e4d1f2e9957e2ce46ec501a4/invoke.js` in your code is the remotely hosted file.

Comment: Hello, is a website embed on extension also a remotely hosted file?